# In a C# method, how do I determine (externally) which methods use a field/property

Tags: c#, powershell, system.reflection

I want to be able to determine the impact of making a change to a Service.  In other words, given the following C# example class, I need to be able to determine if I change **MyServiceWithConfig** that I:

- **will** impact the route /feature/my-route-with-config
- will **not** impact the route /feature/my-route

```cs
    [RoutePrefix("feature")]
    public sealed class MyWebApiController : ApiController
    {
        public MyWebApiController() 
            : this(
                  new MyService(),
                  new MyServiceWithConfig(StaticClass.Configuration))
        {
            // noop
        }

        private MyWebApiController(
            MyService myService, 
            MyServiceWithConfig myServiceWithConfig)
        {
            this.MyServiceInstance = myService;
            this.MyServiceWithConfigInstance = myServiceWithConfig;
        }

        private MyService MyServiceInstance { get; }

        private MyServiceWithConfig MyServiceWithConfigInstance { get; }

        [HttpGet,
            Route("my-route")]
        public async Task<object> Get()
        {
            return await this.MyServiceInstance.DoWork();
        }

        [HttpGet,
            Route("my-route-with-config")]
        public async Task<object> GetWithConfig()
        {
            return await this.MyServiceWithConfigInstance.DoWork();
        }
    }
```

What I have done so far (using reflection in PowerShell 5)

- Find all Types that have a base class of ApiController
- Of those types I know

  - If they have a private field or property of type MyServiceWithConfig
  - Which methods are routes and what those actual routes are

What I am not able to determine how to do:
- Determine that only one of these routes actually *references* **this.MyServiceWithConfigInstance**

From what I've read in other posts - it does not look like I can determine usage of a field using reflection.  Is this something that I can use another tool to do?  It has to be something I can automate because I need it to scan thousands of classes and it isn't practical to process one class at a time.

Is this something that I can leverage Roslyn for?

Thanks!

Note: I can post the PowerShell, but that doesn't seem to be helpful as it is over 100 lines so far.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert on this, but as far as I know Roslyn operates on source code, not assemblies.  So if you wanted to do your comparison against the source code, then you should be able to use Roslyn (though I don't know how).  If you want to do your comparison against a compiled assembly then you will need to find/write a disassembler that gives you something you can turn into an object graph.

Comment: Agrees with Sam, I've been able to do similar things with Roslyn, you can get started with this great tutorial https://joshvarty.com/learn-roslyn-now/

Comment: i dont think you can do this thru reflection since reflection doesnt know what instance you passed to the constructor. roslyn might be your only option here

Comment: Thanks.  I'm working with Roslyn now and once I have a working solution I'll post it as the answer.